# Скрипт для выполнения команд на удаленном оборудовании по ssh

Tags: python, paramiko

Имеется такой скрипт на python:

```
import sys
import time
import paramiko 
import os
import cmd
import datetime

now = datetime.datetime.now()

username = 'xxx'
password = 'xxx'

from zenoss import Zenoss
zenoss = Zenoss('http://x.x.x.x:8080/', 'xx', 'xx')

with open('/home/xxxx/hosts_all.txt', 'w') as f:
    for device in zenoss.get_devices()['devices']:
            print(device['name'], file=f)
    f.close()

f = open('/home/xxxx/hosts_all.txt', 'r')
read_f = f.readlines()
f.close()
for i in range(1, len(read_f)):

    remote_conn_pre = paramiko.SSHClient()


    remote_conn_pre.set_missing_host_key_policy(
         paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    remote_conn_pre.connect(read_f[i], username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
    print("SSH connection established to %s" % read_f[i])

    remote_conn = remote_conn_pre.invoke_shell()
    print("Interactive SSH session established")

    list_of_comm = ["environment no more\n", "admin display-config\n"]

    for i in range(len(list_of_comm)):
        remote_conn.send(list_of_comm[i])

        time.sleep(2)

        output = remote_conn.recv(5000)
        filename = "%s_%.2i-%.2i-%i" % (read_f[i],now.day,now.month,now.year)
        print(str(output) + '\n', file=filename)
```

Скрипт парсит БД системы мониторинга узлов Zenoss. Составляет их список в файле. Далее на основании списка узлов запускается цикл хождения по ssh и сбора в другой файл вывода команд. Но при запуске скрипта выводится ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conf_backup.py", line 43, in <module>
    remote_conn_pre.connect(read_f[i], username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 283, in connect
    to_try = list(self._families_and_addresses(hostname, port))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/paramiko/client.py", line 187, in _families_and_addresses
    addrinfos = socket.getaddrinfo(hostname, port, socket.AF_UNSPEC, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.4/socket.py", line 533, in getaddrinfo
    for res in _socket.getaddrinfo(host, port, family, type, proto, flags):
socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known
```

Вопрос, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Ошибка произошла в строке `remote_conn_pre.connect`, а причиной было `socket.gaierror: [Errno -2] Name or service not known`

Comment: в какой строке находится ошибка, я понимаю, спасибо)
С этой ошибкой я разобрался, в каждом элементе списка содержался ненужный перенос строки. теперь возникла другая, при попытке сохранить вывод в файл - `filename = "%s_%.2i-%.2i-%i" % (read_f[1],now.day,now.month,now.year)
print(str(output) + '\n', file=filename)` ошибка `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'write'`. Я понимаю, что filename это строка, а не файл. Вопрос, как лучше записать эту операцию, чтобы вывод сохранялся в файл, названный по определенному шаблону?

Comment: filename = "%s_%.2i-%.2i-%i" % (read_f[1],now.day,now.month,now.year)

f = open(filename, mode='w')
print(str(output) + '\n', file=f)
f.close()

Comment: Спасибо, уже решил эту задачу таким образом - `filename = "%s_%.2i-%.2i-%i" % (read_f[i].replace('\n', ''),now.day,now.month,now.year)
            with open(filename, 'w') as f:
                f.write(str(output)`
Еще вопрос, если remote_conn_pre.connect выдает ошибку `Name or service not known`, те узел не отвечает. Как ее обойти и не дать скрипту прерывать выполнение? Обычная конструкция `if remote_conn_pre.connect(....):` не работает

Comment: Посидев, подумав, понял что обыгрывать нужно с помощью исключений. Вставил следующую конструкцию - `try:
            remote_conn_pre.connect(read_f[i]), username=username, password=password, look_for_keys=False, allow_agent=False)
    except socket.gaierror:
        print("Could not connect to %s \n" % read_f[i])
        continue
    finally:`

Однако это породило новую ошибку - `During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred: NameError: name 'socket' is not defined`

Answer (score 1):

Решение нашел, не хватало строчки import socket. Теперь скрипт работает в полном объеме.